# Received offer letter without any verbal interview

Tags: recruitment

Recently I got an offer letter from a company without any verbal interview only by filling up the online interview form. Is it genuine?

Comment: Just call and ask them. If it's from a legit well known company in the US with a correct e-mail address, it could be. If it's from a dear friend in Nigeria, probably not.

Comment: Would YOU hire someone you don't know simply by having them fill out an application form, where they can make any claim they want?

Comment: "Genuine" or not (and I'd be surprised if there wasn't *something* wrong here) then at the very least they are extremely disorganised and unprofessional. Do you really want to work for a firm like that? I wouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

This would-be employer did not investigate you very carefully. You still should investigate them carefully.

Ordinarily that's part of the interview process. You meet your would-be boss; you see their premises; you can make a judgement on whether they are really engaged in business.

But in this case you haven't yet had that chance. If I were you I'd respond to their offer by saying you'd like to come in person to accept it and meet them.

I would, if I were you, investigate them carefully online as well. You might consider talking to a customer or two.

If they ask you for money, or for information about your bank account or credit cards, at this stage, **it is a scam.** Break off contact.